# Filter query, when duplicates found, return one with the max value of the duplicate field

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, duplicates

I'm struggling to query my table.

I have the following table

```
CARS
----
ID
MAKE&MODEL
YEAR
PRICE
```

I want to return a single car for each MAKE where the price is highest.

Example:

```
1, FORD_FOCUS, 2004, 1000
2, FORD_FOCUS, 2005, 1200
3, FORD_FIESTA, 2004, 700
4, FORD_FIESTA, 2006, 900
```

I would expect the query to return

```
2, FORD_FOCUS, 2005, 1200
4, FORD_FIESTA, 2006, 900
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I'm working with PL/SQL.

Comment: I have tried group by clause and didn't help much. I have also tried using subquery with where clause (where rownum = 1), joins, etc.

Comment: you should include it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is using `row_number()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by MAKE&MODEL order by price desc) as seqnum
      from cars c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This is much more complicated than I thought. It works great though!

Comment: I would use RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER() if you want to return both rows if the car had the same top price for two years.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton . . . I would often agree with you, but I think the OP is unambiguous:  "I  want to return *a single car* for each MAKE where the price is highest."

Comment: @Gordon - yep, You are correct sir. I hadn't noticed that word in the OP and I'm not about to pretend I know his/her business rules better than they do.